# How to make simple star rating using php?

Tags: rating

I want to make a star rating display. Here is my code.

```
<?php $rate = 4; ?>

<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
```

I want to make it: for example if $rate = 3 show 3x star, 2x star_border.
if $rate = 4 show 4x star, 1x star_border

Here is my too long code. I want shorter and more practical.

```
<?php $rate = 1;?>
<?php if ($rate == 1): ?>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
<?php elseif ($rate == 2): ?>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
<?php elseif ($rate == 3): ?>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
<?php elseif ($rate == 4): ?>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>
<?php elseif ($rate == 5): ?>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: Yes. I tried 5 different if loop. But it is too long. I am searching practical and shortest way.

Comment: Show us your best effort.

Comment: I updated the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should serve you well.

```
<?php
$rate = 3;
for ($x = 0; $x < $rate; $x++) {
    echo '<i class="material-icons md-18">star</i>';
}
for ($x = 0; $x < 5-$rate; $x++) {
    echo '<i class="material-icons md-18">star_border</i>';
}
?>
```

You echo as many starts as your rating says. And then you echo star borders as many as needed.